# throw new Error Invalid transport must be an object with a log method

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, npm, winston

trying to run node server.js file to execute port listening http_server but its not working please help me fix this issue.

```
var socket = require('socket.io'),
    express = require('express'),
    https = require('https')
    http = require('http'),
    logger = require('winston');



logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, { colorize: true, timestamp: true });

logger.info('SocketIO > listening on port');


var app = express();
var http_server = http.createServer(app).listen(3001);


function emitNewOrder(http_server) {

  var io = socket.listen ( http_server );

  // First listen to a connection and run the call back function
  io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {


  });


}

emitNewOrder(http_server);
```

Error: Invalid transport, must be an object with a log method.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96P3t.png)

Comment: What does this question/issue have to do with PHP?

Comment: Yes exactly with PHP

Comment: _"Yes exactly with PHP"_ - That made no sense as an answer to my previous question. You have added the PHP tag while the question seem to be about node.js (which is very different from PHP).

Comment: Yes its node.js. building real time display database update with socket.io and PHP

Comment: If the question has to do with PHP, you should explain how and post the relevant PHP code (including potential errors). If the PHP part works and it's just the nodejs part you're asking about, please remove that tag. When you add multiple technologies and only post code for one (and not even mention the other), it makes the question very unclear and harder to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using incorrectly the winston library. As you can see in the documentation the correct init for a logger and transport must be like this:

```
winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
});
logger.clear()
logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({ colorize: true, timestamp: true }));

logger.info('SocketIO > listening on port');
```

inside the logger you can define transports. More documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)

P.D. I agree with @M. Eriksson that this question is not related to PHP in any form so you must remove the tag